# How to get data from server in JSON format by using ASP.NET c#?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net

How to get data from server in JSON format by using ASP.NET c#?

I know how to get data in JSON format using php but i'm trying to do the same but using c#.

Comment: same thing ....for getting data in JSON from server  why you consider  language?

Comment: I'd suggest you provide more details, e.g.are you trying to get the data from external server or do you want your own server to return the data in Json format?

Comment: Yes i want my own server to return data in JSON format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider following when you post your JSON from server side:

1. data: JSON.stringify(person),
2. contentType: "application/json"

On your client side:

1. get the request body from HttpCurrent.Context.Request.InputStream.
2. read the input stream and convert to string
3. deserialize the json object

Do it like this::

```
string json;
using(var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream)){
        json = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
var person = Json.Decode(json);
```

Tutorial: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/220/posting-data-with-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-razor-web-pages

[How to: Request Data Using the WebRequest Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f(v=vs.110).aspx)